# Use 2 keycodes to return event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

I'm 3 weeks into learning JS, and am working on a project to build a playable piano. When typing the letter c, it will play the note c. That part is working fine, but now I want the user to hold the control key and type c to make it play a different note, c#. How would i set this up? Below is what I've tried working on, but I can't get this to work.

Any refactoring advice is also helpful - I'm going to have a lot more keys played

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (playNote) =>{

    if(playNote.key == 'c'){
        document.getElementById('low-c').play();    
            }
 
    if(playNote.key == 'c' && playNote.cntrlkey == true){
        document.getElementById('low-c#').play();
            }
    }
```

Comment: I would change the `low-c#` to be `low-c-sharp` as `#` is often used as a ID selector and this will avoid ensuring your code handles that in all places.

Comment: You have a typo.  The [keydown event property you're looking for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey)  is called `ctrlKey` not `cntrlkey`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) for keyboard events.
You will find a value for if the ctrl key is pressed under `playNote.ctrlKey`
Then do

```js
if(playNote.key == 'c' && playNote.ctrlKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', evt =>
  {
  if (evt.key == 'c') 
    {
    if (evt.ctrlKey)
      document.getElementById('low-c#').play();
    else
      document.getElementById('low-c').play();
    }
  });
```

Comment: This code-only answer could be improved by including a brief explanation.

Comment: @Wyck For me this is just the question of a beginner in programming, and from experience I know that these posts here are of little importance to be kept on this site, and will have to be purged for space reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. As the other answer mentions, the property you want to read is `ctrlKey`, not `cntrlkey`. Another problem is a logical one - you need to check for the ctrl key press before checking for just c press, and it also needs to be with an if else. Otherwise, both c and c# will be played on pressing ctrl+c.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "c" && event.ctrlKey == true) {
    document.getElementById("low-c#").play();
  } else if (event.key === "c") {
    document.getElementById("low-c").play();
  }
});
```

Comment: don't really need the `== true` part

Answer (score 0):

This code plays different piano notes when you press the `c` key, and whether it's combined with the `Ctrl` key or not. If you press `Ctrl + c`, it plays *`low-c#`*; if you press just `c`, it plays *`low-c`*.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (playNote) => {
    if (playNote.key === 'c' && playNote.ctrlKey) {
        document.getElementById('low-c#').play();
    } else if (playNote.key === 'c') {
        document.getElementById('low-c').play();
    }
});
```